# SCP Hidden Password Prompt

Tags: linux, command-line, scp

I would like to transfer files in a folder from my laptop to a server via SCP like so:

```
scp -r /folder/path/on/laptop user@server:folder/to/save/to
```

This works perfectly. However, I am using an arduino to type this command (and some others) into a terminal so it does this all automatically.

Here'e the problem: I want the password prompt (arduino types out password) to be hidden while the status of SCP (file transfer info) is shown. If I use "clear" after the command, the transfer is fast enough that it doesn't show the prompt, but also erases the transfer info from screen.

Would I use the -B option to accomplish this? or is there any other way? I am doing this is because I don't necessarily want to store the keys on either machine.

Comment: When you run scp (or ssh) interactively and it prompts you for a password, ssh normally disables character echo so that the typed password isn't visible on the screen. If the password is visible for you, you probably need to understand why that's happening in the first place before you can prevent it.

Comment: the password itself is not visible, but the prompt is. I want to get rid of the prompt `user@server's password:`.

Comment: May I know why this prompt bothers you? Maybe there's [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/355310) here.

Comment: The prompt doesn't bother me. It's more of an aesthetic thing. I just wanted the output to not display it.